# Reshaping CSV columns in python

Tags: python, csv

I have my data in this form

[image]

and the required form of data is

[image]

Can anybody help me in this regard?

---

The content of the initial CSV file as text is:

```
var1,var2,col1,col2,col3
a,f,1,2,3
b,g,4,5,6
c,h,7,8,9
d,i,10,11,12
```

Comment: Beware, a csv file is not what you have shown. It is a text file and has delimiters and optionaly quote or escape characters. If you show some lines as text, with the delimiter, then we could propose you various ways, using or not pandas.

Comment: var1,var2,col1,col2,col3
a,f,1,2,3
b,g,4,5,6
c,h,7,8,9
d,i,10,11,12

Comment: @SergeBallesta are you asking about this?

Comment: Exactly! But I expected it in the question itself. I have made the edit for you. But remember it for your next questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly with the csv module. You just read from the initial file, and write up to 3 rows per initial row into the resulting file:

```
with open('in.csv') as fdin, open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fdin)
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    header = next(rd)       # read and process header
    _ = wr.writerow(header[:2] + ['columns',''])
    for row in rd:                                  # loop on rows
        for i in range(3):                          # loop on the 3 columns
            try:   
                row2 = row[:2] + ['col{}'.format(i+1), row[2 + i]]
                _ = wr.writerow(row2)
            except IndexError:                      # prevent error on shorter line
                break
```

If you intend to do heavy data processing, you should contemplate using the Pandas module.

With the data sample, it gives:

```
var1,var2,columns,
a,f,col1,1
a,f,col2,2
a,f,col3,3
b,g,col1,4
b,g,col2,5
b,g,col3,6
c,h,col1,7
c,h,col2,8
c,h,col3,9
d,i,col1,10
d,i,col2,11
d,i,col3,12
```